# How to use a local copy of a "Database First" Microsoft SQL Database for Testing Purposes

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using a Microsoft SQL database in our production environment. The project uses a database first approach and the entity framework.

Now, I have exported said production database to a local deployment of Microsoft SQL server. For testing purposes, I want to connect to that local deployment with the connection string

```
metadata=res://*/DataModels.MyModel.csdl|
res://*/DataModels.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModels.MyModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data 
source=localhost;initial catalog=model;integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

However, when I try to send data to the database I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 
An error occurred while executing the command definition. 
See the inner exception for details. 
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 
'dbo.my_db_object_name'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, 
Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

Firing the same request to the production database works fine, however. Any ideas what I might be missing? The database name, object/table names are the same for production and local databases. Even queries that I send through the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio work fine on both instances.

I assume it has to do something with the entity framework that I'm missing here. Any ideas? Do I somehow need to update the data models for production and testing?

Comment: did You check web config for old database connections?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? when I change the connection string, shouldn't that be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The connection string was wrong:

```
initial catalog=model
```

must be replaced with

```
initial catalog=my_db
```

Works like a charm now :-)